# ES6 - Reorder an Array with respect to an Object

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array which is like :

```
const my_array = [
"S T"
"O P"
"Lend"
"GT"
"CT"
"AC"
];
```

and an object according to which this array is being reordered:

```
const AN_ORDER = {
  'Lend': 1,
  'C T': 2,
  'S T': 3,
  'AC': 4,
  'O P': 5
};
```

for which there is already a solution done as 
//keys and sortBy from Lodash

```
const new_array = keys(my_array);
return sortBy(new_array, ar => AN_ORDER[ar] || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

this yields me new array as:

```
["Lend", "AC", "O P", "S T", "GT", "C T"]
```

I tried looking into documentation of this usage, but I do not understand the idea of second argument being used here in sortBy.

Now my need is to reorder the **my_array** in below sequence:

```
['Lend', 'C T', 'S T', 'GT', 'AC', 'O P']
```

Please help me understand the implementation and suggest a way I can reorder in the same logic.

Comment: You have "CT" at the top, and "C T" at the bottom.  Also you have "keys()" there which would not give you the output you have shown.  Is this the actual code you are using?  The output looks like it is behaving as expected, and the output you are asking for is not consistent

Comment: AN_ORDER is an array or object?

Comment: It looks like you were given a problem to solve, and you've misunderstood what they were asking for.  You are only supposed to sort into the array the ones they ask you to sort, everything else is supposed to stay in the position they were before.  lodash cannot do this for you.  You're also supposed to ignore whitespaces in the comparison, and use the value in the AN object.

Answer (score 2):

Your key 'G T' is not in object 'AN_ORDER' so my output will look different than yours. but it's working right.

```
const myArray = [
        'S T',
        'O P',
        'Lend',
        'GT',
        'C T',
        'AC'
        ];


const AN_ORDER = {
        'Lend': 1,
        'C T': 2,
        'S T': 3,
        'AC': 4,
        'O P': 5
        };

const sortedCollection = _.sortBy(myArray, item => {
        return AN_ORDER[item];
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have add array in second argument, here you can mention callback function or property name.

Here is the working solution

```js
const my_array = [
"S T",
"O P",
"Lend",
"GT",
"C T",
"AC"
];

var AN_ORDER = {
  "Lend": 1,
  "C T": 2,
  "S T": 3,
  "AC": 4,
  "O P": 5
};

console.log(_.sortBy(my_array, [a => {
return (AN_ORDER[a] || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
}]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what AN_ORDER represents, as there isn't enough information on what it represents exactly.
Uses the keys in AN_ORDER in the final array, because the specified output above uses that.  Strips spaces before searching for matching keys, using a Set to search if they exist, and using an offset of 0.5 to insert non-existing keys into AN_ORDER for sorting.

```js
const my_array = [
"S T",
"O P",
"Lend",
"GT",
"CT",
"AC"
];

const AN_ORDER = {
  'Lend': 1,
  'C T': 2,
  'S T': 3,
  'AC': 4,
  'O P': 5
};

const keys = new Set(Object.keys(AN_ORDER).map(x=>x.replace(/\s/g,'')))

my_array.forEach( (x,i)=>!keys.has(x.replace(/\s/g,'')) && (AN_ORDER[x]=i+0.5) )

my_obj = _.sortBy(Object.entries(AN_ORDER), ([,x])=>x).map(([x,])=>x)

console.log(my_obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
```